# Compilation error with Log4J

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, log4j

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building parqueos-api 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ parqueos-api ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ parqueos-api ---
Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\samuelmolina\Documents\NetBeansProjects\parqueos-api\target\classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.apache.log4j.Logger not found
1 error
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.375s
Finished at: Thu Oct 29 12:36:23 CST 2015
Final Memory: 15M/82M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project parqueos-api: Compilation failure
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.apache.log4j.Logger not found
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Retry by installing `log4j`.

Comment: and adding the right tags to the question...